# Json data parses incorrectly

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, laravel, express

React JS front end, Express JS middleware, Laravel Backend
When the data is sent from react to express then to laravel the data is not parsed in laravel in the correct format.

React Front end posting to express

```
  const data = await fetch(`${config.appURL}/deployment/stage1`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(form),
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});
```

Express Mid

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
if (req.session.token) {
request(
  {
    method: "POST",
    uri: `${config.apiURI}/deployment/stage1`,
    body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${req.session.token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  },
```

Laravel

```
    public function stage1(Request $request){

    return $request->all();
```

Tried json_decode, receive error expects param 1 to be string, tried accessing the variable in laravel $request->my_field, receive error can not access of none object

Comment: check you generated JSON is valid or not. [Online validator](https://jsonlint.com/?code=)

Comment: Why you tagged node and express?

Comment: Does your Express server have middleware that parses the JSON into `req.body`?

Comment: Is `JSON.stringify(form)` the actual JSON you want to send?  Did you look at what that creates?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, I was missing the accept header

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
if (req.session.token) {
request(
{
method: "POST",
uri: `${config.apiURI}/deployment/stage1`,
body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
headers: {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${req.session.token}`,
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Accept": "application/json"
},
},
```